# PHP update SQL table to a logged in user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a logged in user's input from a text box to be inserted into a column on their row. Right now I am able to insert data into my database but it comes up as a new record. I'm struggling to find a way to point it to the specific logged in user so it adds to that row rather than creating a new record.

form code in `payment.php`:

```
<form class="test" action="payment.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" required class="text" name='bitaddress' placeholder="Public Key...">
    <input class="wow shake" data-wow-delay="0.3s" type="submit" value="Accept" name="accept" />
</form>
```

PHP code in `payment.php`:

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['accept'])) { 
        require 'paymentProccess.php';    
    }
}
?>
```

lastly my code inside `paymentProccess.php`:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';

$bitaddress = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['bitaddress']);

$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$active = $_SESSION['active'];
$paid = $_SESSION['paid'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (bitaddress) " . "VALUES ('$bitaddress')";
if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

}
?>
```

Comment: You need to have `user_id` field in `users` table in order to have single value of bitaddress per user.

Comment: there are quite a few ways to do this, what have you tried to resolve this yourself? That way if you made a mistake somewhere, we'd probably be able to help by pointing them out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've tried a few different ways but can't seem to get it to stick. Also, I can use everything else in the table as a $_SESSION but for some reason when I try to get the auto_increment id i get an error

Comment: *"so it adds to that row rather than creating a new record"* - Can you be more specific about that and to provide some form of example?

Comment: *"i get an error"* @Mark.S what's the error?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry. what I meant to say was I need it to take that data from the text box and input it to the 'bitaddress' column in my database

Comment: @Fred-ii- the error is "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pals\payment.php on line 17". all my other session variables are fine though

Comment: the undefined index is most likely coming from your query, doesn't seem to be a php issue here, since there's no code posted for it. You'll most likely have to include the `id` column in the query and use `''` as the VALUES value. I think you're looking to want to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html if you want to and as you stated in the post: *"so it adds to that row rather than creating a new record"*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanking you kindly. Having a read through now. my syntax was off thats why I was getting the error. I just reviewed it now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, have a good weekend.

Comment: You're most welcome Mark and thanks. Enjoy your weekend also. Don't go scaring anybody half to death now! (grin). Happy Hallowee'n.

Comment: Btw Mark, you know that Stack does lets you post your own answer/solution. If you decide to do that. ping me back and I'd be glad to upvote it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- finally got it to work. I'm a little over my head here when it comes to php so i'll definitely be reading more of the documentations. cheers from Melb, Aus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments of help. After 3-4 hours I ended up working it out if anyone else has this issue.

firstly I got the "id" for the user which is my primary key.

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

then on my `paymentProccess.php` page I used this:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';

$bitaddress = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['bitaddress']);

$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$active = $_SESSION['active'];
$paid = $_SESSION['paid'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET bitaddress = '$bitaddress' WHERE id = '$id'";

if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

}
?>
```

note: I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it. It could have security flaws etc. But when i refreshed phpMyAdmin I had a massive amount of stress relieved.

Comment: Glad to see you fixed it Mark. In regards to security, it'd be best to use a prepared statement http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php - `real_escape_string()`'s ok, but not the best. *Cheers*